# How to save previous version in audit table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created the following table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Audit.Awards]
(SessionID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  
ID INT NOT NULL,
Name  NVARCHAR(max) NOT NULL,  
Abstract  NVARCHAR(max) NOT NULL,    
ChangedDate DATETIME NOT NULL Default GETDATE(),  
ChangedBy NVARCHAR(40) )
```

and I created the following trigger

```
create trigger tIU on [dbo].[Awards] after UPDATE,insert
as
declare @ID int; 
 declare @name varchar(max);
declare @abstract varchar(max);

begin
select @ID=i.ID,@name=i.name,@abstract=i.abstract from inserted i;
insert into [dbo].[Audit.Awards](ID,name, abstract) values(@ID,@name,@abstract)
end
```

The trigger currently saves the new data from the update in the audit.awards table. How do I save the data that was overwritten instead?

Comment: Are you asking how you save only the data that has been changed?

Comment: You also create a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger

Comment: Your trigger is fatally flawed. Inserted and deleted can contain more than one record. You NEVER assign a value to a parameter from inserted or deleted because they are not scalar. Use a select statement in your insert instead.

Answer (score 3):

In your trigger, select from `deleted` instead of `inserted`.

And by the way, you should do this with an INSERT..SELECT instead of using local variables.

```
insert into [dbo].[Audit.Awards](ID,name, abstract)
select ID,name,abstract from deleted
```

Comment: And if you want to populate changedBy field, then you need to grab the user, it can be a constraint on the column: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/current-user-transact-sql